# Django multiple annotations returns wrong results

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate

I am trying to create an annotation in a django queryset. The annotation is a Count of reverse foreign key based on a condition. The issue I am having is that when I do the count for one reverse foreign key with a condition I get the right data, but when I do two annotations, one for each reverse foreign key.

Here is the queryset with Count annotation for one reverse foreign key:

```
ExamResponse.objects.filter(
        course_class__course=course,
        exam__exam_type=Exam.PRACTICE,
        user__is_demo=False,
        ended__isnull=False,
        id=125752
    ).order_by(
        'user_id',
        'started'
    ).annotate(
        total_ecq_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(
                    choice_questions__response_time__gte=ENGAGEMENT_THRESHOLD,
                    choice_questions__id__isnull=False,
                    then=1
                ),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            ), 
            distinct=True
        ),
    ).values('total_ecq_count')
```

Results (Correct Result):

`<QuerySet [{'total_ecq_count': 1}]>`

The query with two Count annotations

```
ExamResponse.objects.filter(
        course_class__course=course,
        exam__exam_type=Exam.PRACTICE,
        user__is_demo=False,
        ended__isnull=False,
        id=125752
    ).order_by(
        'user_id',
        'started'
    ).annotate(
        total_ecq_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(
                    choice_questions__response_time__gte=ENGAGEMENT_THRESHOLD,
                    choice_questions__id__isnull=False,
                    then=1
                ),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            ), 
            distinct=True
        ),
        total_etq_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(
                    text_questions__response_time__gte=ENGAGEMENT_THRESHOLD,
                    text_questions__id__isnull=False,
                    then=1
                ),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            ), 
            distinct=True
        ),
    ).values('total_ecq_count', 'total_etq_count')
```

Results: (The total_ecq_count went from 1 to 3!!!)

`<QuerySet [{'total_ecq_count': 3, 'total_etq_count': 4}]>`

Answer (score 2):

I just found this article, apparently, it is a known bug that two annotations for two different foreign keys create duplicate counts. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25861